# compare a collection element to a field value elastic

Tags: elasticsearch

How to compare the first value of a collection to value of a field in elasticsearch

I have an elastic result that looks like this

```
 "externalLocations": {
    "binaries": {
     "standard": 
       "some_value"
     }
  },

 "attributes": {
    "mainUrl@Media_str": [
       "some_value"
     ]
  }
```

On my query I to do something like this, but it's not working

```
"query": {
"bool": {
  "must": [
    {
      "query_string": {
        "query": "binaries.standard == attributes.mainUrl@Media_str[0]"
      }
    }
  ]
}
}
```

Comment: I believe this post may help you  https://discuss.elastic.co/t/matching-two-fields-with-the-same-value-across-two-indices/101828

Comment: tkx @Green, as I understood from the post it's not possible to compare two fields in the same document elastic

Comment: Yes. this what was answered in the beginning, afterwords the last comment mention Vega as a possible option with some guide lines